# How to properly validate PNG header in java?

Tags: java, validation, header, png

I'm trying to write a function which will check if PNG file is not corrupted. [Here](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/io/read-file-content-into-byte-array/) I found a function, also provided below, which stores file bytes into its own byte array. I know that the first eight bytes of a PNG file always contain the same decimal values 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10 (hex: 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a).
When I print the context of the byte array which starts with `-1-40-1-3201674707370011007207200-1-370-124022222232235333565555686666681088888810101010101 ...`  and then convert it to decimal values I don't see the magic number in the beginning. Please, what have I misunderstood? I would like to read the image and compare its header to either decimal or hex values.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        File file = new File("src/resources/dog.png");

        readContentIntoByteArray(file);
    }
```

```
 private static byte[] readContentIntoByteArray(File file)
    {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        try
        {
            //convert file into array of bytes
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bFile);
            fileInputStream.close();
            for (int i = 0; i < bFile.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.print((char) bFile[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bFile;
    }
```

Comment: *FYI:* To read the entire file into a `byte[]`, use `byte[] bFile = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("dog.png"))`

Comment: *"what have I misunderstood?"* How to print bytes. To print a byte in hex form, use `printf("%02x ", bFile[i])`. To print a byte is decimal form, use `printf("%d ", bFile[i])` or `print(bFile[i] + " ")`.

Comment: @Andreas indeed i forgot to specify the type when printing. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the actual bytes as characters to the terminal, not the representation of those bytes in decimal or hex, as @Andreas says.

You can check the header with:

```
        byte[] data = readContentIntoByteArray(file);
        byte[] expected = new byte[] {-119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10};
        for (int i = 0; i < expected.length; i++) {
            if (expected[i] != data[i]) {
                System.out.println("mismatch at " + i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This kind of check is what I was trying to implement. Later I found out that my "dog.png" even though it has png extension its header looks like this `ff d8 ff e0-00 10 4a 46-49 46 00 01-01 00 00 48` instead of `89 50 4e 47-0d 0a 1a 0a-00 00 00 0d-49 48 44 52` and this is what confuses me the most how it is even possible while still not being currupted and showing the picture just fine.